# What website will speak Cantonese to me?

Tags: cantonese

My parents are born in Hong Kong so I can speak Cantonese semi-fluently, although I cannot write.

I've been learning Mandarin and I find that my cantonese has been useful because if the word is used in Cantonese as well, its fairly easy to know the usage.

I find that a lot of the times I'm translating Mandarin into Cantonese into english basically.

I was wondering if anyone has come across a voice program / website similar to Google translate, which allows you to enter some characters in and it'll say it in Cantonese. All the ones I've come across so far speak in Mandarin.

Comment: Sorry Chits, but this type of questions are not allowed on SE, because they don't fit well the format. Usually asking for "does anyone know..." or "is there any..." invites other users to provide lots of answers. Check the description below. :) In case you need help or you want to discuss the decision, please consider asking a question in our [Meta].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This one from 香港中文大学](http://sepc495.se.cuhk.edu.hk/cuvocal/)
it's easy to search for cantonese resources from HK websites.

Comment: awesome! that's exactly what i was looking for. cheers :)

Comment: @Chits Improve your question. If you leave it as is, I'll be forced to delete it sooner or later.

Comment: @Alenanno : I've tried to improve the title as per the FAQ, but yeah I'm not sure what else I can do. The answer Fivesheep was exactly what I was looking for so IMO, it was fairly constructive.